# How to disable Unigrid action

Tags: kentico, unigrid

I have created a module that maintains a list of color schemes. Some of the color schemes are default schemes and should never be deleted. However, some are custom schemes created by end users. I have an IsCustom field defined and it is set to true if the end user created the color scheme. you can see the value of that flag under the "Custome Color Scheme" column in the attached screenshot. My question is  how do I disable the Delete action if IsCustom=false OR if {%CurrentUser.UserIsGlobalAdministrator%}. So for example, the only item that can be deleted in the screenshot is the Sublime color scheme. Unless, the user is a global administrator.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to:

1. [Create a listing extender](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Creating+extenders+for+module+interface+pages#Creatingextendersformoduleinterfacepages-Updatingthelistinggriddefinition)
2. Assign it to the listing control [image: Assign extender to the listing control]
3. [Implement `OnExternalDataBound` event handler](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/UniGrid#UniGrid-Implementingcustomfunctionality) according to your requirements

Comment: This may be the fix. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: I don't see a way to get access to the "Delete" action inside the OnExternalDataBound method. It only calls this for the "Other actions" button.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the action by leveraging the `OnExternalDataBound` event.

There is actually an example in [this documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/UniGrid#UniGrid-Implementingcustomfunctionality) where the `OnExternalDataBound` is used to disable action if the user is administrator. It would be just a matter of some custom condition to achieve exactly what you need.

Comment: I saw the documentation. However, I don't have a web form code behind file that I know of. The grid is defined in a default.xml file and there are no .cs files associated with it. So, I'm not sure where to put the Page_Load code as in the example.